# Page renders differently locally in IE8 despite identical HTML, CSS & Document + Browser mode settings

Tags: html, css, iis, internet-explorer-8

I am currently trying to sort out a rendering issue in IE8 - I am using IE10 with the Browser Mode set to 'IE8' and the Document Mode set to 'IE8 standards'.

I have compared the HTML and CSS and they are identical. It renders as it is supposed to locally but when viewed on the server the background image does not display and instead is just black.

```
<a href="/test/" class="promo" style="background-image: url('/test.jpg');">Test</a>
```

Both the local site and the server are using IIS 7.5.

I have the following line in my HTML but removing it or changing it has no effect since I am manually selecting IE8+IE8 standards in the browser

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

I am certain that the HTML, CSS and image are identical and the image is reachable on the server (I can visit it in the browser)

I really can't think of what more I can try right now.

Comment: The IE developer tools are a bad joke. you can download VMs from Microsoft here: http://www.modern.ie to view the actual results.

Comment: Looks like a path issue to me. Mind show us your live demo?